# Trying to use cursor on one database using select from another db

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to wrap my head around cursors. I have task to transfer data from one database to another, but they have slightly diffrent schemas. Let's say I have TableOne (Id, Name, Gold) and TableTwo (Id, Name, Lvl). I want to take all records from TableTwo and insert it into TableOne, but it can be duplicated data on Name column. So if single record from TableTwo exist (on Name column comparison) in TableOne, I want to skip it, if don't - create record in TableOne with unique Id.

I was thinking about looping on each record in TableTwo, and for every record check if it's exist in TableOne. So, how do I make this check without making call to another database every time? I wanted first select all record from TableOne, save it into variable and in loop itself make check against this variable. Is this even possible in SQL? I'm not so familiar with SQL, some code sample would help a lot.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio if that matters. And of course, TableOne and TableTwo exists in diffrent databases.

Comment: I think you mean 'cursor'. Having said that, cursors are generally not required for most operations. Definitely not for this operation. You just have to write a single select statement that removes duplicates then you insert those results in to the target table. In one SQL statement, without looping. Is this database on the same SQL Server?

Comment: Yes they are, and it is not so simple since I would lost data along with removed records. I show very simplified tables, in reallity they looks like T1(Id, Name, Color, Level, Money, Customer, AnotherRealtedData) T2(Id, Name, Color, DataForTable3, DataForTable4). Operation I want to perform will be done for couple tables.

Comment: From what you have explained it's simple enough. You need to work out what the comparison fields are then you use `select * from sourcedb..sourcetable where not exists (select * from targetdb..targettable where targettable.joinkey = sourcetable.joinkey)`. Then it will only select records that don't already exist, based on your join key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Insert into table1(id,name,gold)
Select id,name,lvl from table2
Where table2.name not in(select t1.name from table1 t1)
```

If you want to add newId for every row you can try

```
Insert into table1(id,name,gold)
Select (select max(m.id) from table1 m) + row_number() over (order by t2.id) ,name,lvl from table2 t2
Where t2.name not in(select t1.name from table1 t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible yes, but I would not recommend it. Looping (which is essentially what a cursor does) is usually not advisable in SQL when a set-based operation will do.

At a high level, you probably want to join the two tables together (the fact that they're in different databases shouldn't make a difference). You mention one table has duplicates. You can eliminate those in a number of ways such as using a `group by` or a `row_number`. Both approaches will require you understanding which rows you want to "pick" and which ones you want to "ignore". You could also do what another user posted in a comment where you do an existence check against the target table using a correlated subquery. That will essentially mean that if any rows exist in the target table that have duplicates you're trying to insert, none of those duplicates will be put in.

As far as cursors are concerned, to do something like this, you'd be doing essentially the same thing, except on each pass of the cursor you would be temporarily assigning and using variables instead of columns. This approach is sometimes called RBAR (for "Rob by Agonizing Row"). On every pass of the cursor or loop, it has to re-open the table, figure out what data it needs, then operate on it. Even if that's efficient and it's only pulling back one row, there's still lots of overhead to doing that query. So while, yes, you can force SQL to do what you've describe, the database engine already has an operation for this (joins) which does it far faster than any loop you could conceivably write

Comment: I don't think that joins are solution here. Wouldn't it just make another table, instead of inserting custom values from one table to another?

Comment: You talked about comparing values between tables in what you were envisioning in your cursor which is pretty much what joins were made for. I see you already got your answer though, using the subquery method, which works just as well. However if you didn't have duplicates, a join would have worked just fine too.